# data from api not showing in chart.js (angular)

Tags: angular, chart.js

my first time i'm use chart.js in angular
i saw alot of video but when i do self and tried alot of time data not shwing in chart maybe i do some wrong in my code

take data from database :
save data into this.visitor

```
get_project():void{
  this.projectService.get_project(1).subscribe(data=>{
this.visitor=data.visitor; <== data.visitor = 5
console.log(data.visitor)
  })
}
```

chart.js code :

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
    this.get_project()
    this.chart()
  }




 chart():void{
    console.log(this.visitor)
          var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
          var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: this.visitor, <<<=== undefine
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'month'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        }
```

Comment: also share you data which is coming from api.

Comment: only data.visitor =5

Comment: first thing is call this method `this.get_project()` in `onAfterViewInit` and when you get the response then call `this.chart()` in subscribe function.

Answer (score -1):

What your doing is that you read the data before it is there.

```
get_project():void{
  return this.projectService.get_project(1)
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.get_project().subscribe(data=>{
        this.visitor=data.visitor;
        console.log(data.visitor);
        this.chart(); // only when the data is fetched, you can render chart
    })
}
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined and why we do like this ? this.visitor has number in original code

Comment: oh when i write console.log(this.visitor) in chart() i got undefine

Comment: sorry, forgot a return statement.

Answer (score -1):

i solve it when subscribe the data i create new value let s = null  and then i add data from subscribe into new value s and that's working

```
chart():void{
  this.projectService.get_project(1).subscribe(data=>{
    let s=null
    s=data.visitor;
    console.log(data.visitor)
  console.log(this.visitor)
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      // The type of chart we want to create
      type: 'line',
  
      // The data for our dataset
      data: {
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'My First dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
              data: [s, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45], 
              fill: true
          }]
      },
  
      // Configuration options go here
      options: {}
  });
})
}
```